# how to check date lies within 10 days in android

Tags: java, android

i have written this code to check given date is within 10 days or outside 10 days but AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY always give 0 . how to check given date lies within 10 days in android or java?

```
long lastdate=1535826537767

if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastdate) < (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 10)) {
    Log.d("Status", "Date within 10 days")       
} else {
    Log.d("Status", "Date within 10 days")
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of “day”? Chunks of time 24-hours long? Calendar days? If calendar, what time zone should be used in perceiving your moment `1535826537767`?

Comment: its in GMT format please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
long ten_days_in_in_millis = 864000000;
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastdate) < ten_days_in_in_millis) {..
```

Comment: This code ignores the issues of time zones affecting the calendar. **Not all days are 24-hours** long. See [the Answer by Desert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52172358/642706) for an example of properly considering time zone effects on date.

Comment: no dear its not working when when i check  with today date its not going inside within 10 days

Comment: can you check with one day before from current date please

Comment: @BasilBourque why can't you focus on the main point of the question? How do you know that the OP hasn't already converted (if at all needed) the date in local time zone? The question is not about time zone issues, and as it stands you can't assume that hasn't been taken care of it beforehand.

Comment: @AnilThakur This code is very simple, the only variable is the date in millis you are checking, if you have correct value for it then this code works.

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

You can make use of [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later to check if a certain date lies within last 10 days.

First: convert lastdate (that you already have) to LocalDate.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(lastdate) ; // A moment in UTC.
LocalDate originalDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(); 
LocalDate tenDaysOldDate= LocalDate.now().minusDays(10); //10 days old date

if (Period.between(tenDaysOldDate, originalDate ).getDays() > 10)
      //greater than 10 days
```

[LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is immutable and thread-safe. This class should be preferred over the problematic Date class.

[Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) is also immutable and thread-safe. It measures time in years, months and days.

---

Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I prefer this solution due to its legibility and the use of current APIs. But the use of Java 8 might be something that is too limitting for some

Comment: Where did you see that the OP is using java 8?

Comment: @FarazDurrani What I am saying is that your answer may not be applicable to the question if they are using java < 8.

Comment: @NiVeR Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).